# Perl: "noisy logs problem" Create array of regex queries from multiple arrays/hashes

Tags: perl, data-structures, yaml

**Problem:**
I need to pull data from auth logs for approx. 30 locations. The logs are in CSV format.
In order for the analysis to be useful the log entries must be matched up with the hours of operation of the locations. The data is stored in directories named for the time period the data covers: eg., data/june1-june30/. The CSV files are simply named with the location code
eg., LOC1.csv , LOC2.csv. Here is a sample of a typical log:

```
2010-06-01, 08:30:00 , 0
2010-06-01, 09:30:00 , 1
2010-06-01, 10:30:00 , 10
2010-06-01, 11:30:00 , 7
2010-06-01, 12:30:00 , 8
2010-06-01, 13:30:00 , 6
2010-06-01, 14:30:00 , 3
2010-06-01, 15:30:00 , 8
2010-06-01, 16:30:00 , 11
```

The entries show the number of successful authenticated sessions during the time period indicated in the 3rd field. The logs represent 24 hours of data which is useless for analysis since the hours of operation differ from location to location. The problem now becomes how to pull only the data that matches the hours of operation. The analysis must show activity for the hours of operation to be useful.

**Setup - so far**
I decided to create a config file using YAML with arrays/hashes for each location.

eg.,

```
- branch: headquarters
  abbrev: HQ
  months: [04, 06]
  DOW: [M, T, W, Th]
  hours:
      M:                [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
      T:                [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
      W:        [09, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
                         16, 17, 18]
      Th:       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
                         19, 20]
```

The months designation shows the busiest months, as that's all we care about.

**Where I'm at**
The code will find the appropriate directories using the months array, then it pulls the correct CSV files using the abbrev array. So I have the files I need stored in an array @files. My question comes down to design. The results must be matched to the appropriate dates for each month. Mondays, Tuesdays ...etc. Do I create month arrays storing the dates for each day of the week?
I'm stuck and unsure where to go from here.

To clarify: The code already pulls the correct
files and loads them into an array ( using globbing and Find::File ) for each branch. The question is now about iterating through the @files array for each branch and pulling the info.

**EDIT:**
as per request: I will put up some code. This is the goods for getting a hold of those files
by the months indicated in the hash. That's the easy part.

```
foreach my $branch (@$config) {
        my $name = $branch->{'branch'};
        my $months = $branch->{'months'};
        my $abbrev = $branch->{'abbrev'};

        # find directories for busy months, load in @dirs
        my @dirs;       
        foreach my $month (@$months) {
                my $regex2 = qr(stats_2010-$month.*);
                map { push(@dirs, $_) if $_ =~ $regex2 } @stats_dir;
        }

        # find csv files within directories, load in @files
        my @files;
        find(\&wanted, @dirs);
        sub wanted {
                push(@files, $_) if $_ =~ /$abbrev\.csv/;
        }
```

**Output:**
The output I'm hoping to get is: The lines from each file representing the hours of operation for that branch. I think they could be output to a separate file for the sake of simplicity. And in the same format. What makes it hard is that you have to match Mondays,Tuesdays ..etc. with dates somehow. This is due to different hours of operation for different days.

Am I making the problem harder than it needs to be? I've sat with this too long and am hoping for a fresh set of eyes to set me straight. My Perl is OK, but I need some help in the design/algorithm dept. I can figure out how to Perlify it, I think. But feel free to post Perl. I love reading good Perl!

Eventually I will average the activity for the Mondays, Tuesdays ...etc. of each month.

Thanks ~

Bubnoff

Comment: It might help to show us some of your code already, and explain the output you need.

Comment: Posted the main part of the code. Using YAML for config. @stats_dir is globbed directories array.

Comment: See below for solution using dlamblin's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the Day of Week to a number when Monday is 1 and Sunday is 7. Then create a hash that looks like `1=>{12=>1,13=>1,14=>1,15=>1,16=>1,17=>1,18=>1},2=>{12=>1,13=>1,14=>1,15=>1,16=>1,17=>1,18=>1},...` (notice how DOW in your YAML is redundant).

so far:

```
use DateTime;
foreach $file (@files) {
  open F "<$file";
  foreach $line (<F>) {
    $line =~ m/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+), (\d+):(\d+):(\d+) , (\d+)/;
    $dt = DateTime->new( year   => $1,
                         month  => $2,
                         day    => $3,
                         hour   => $4,
                         minute => $5,
                         second => $6,
                       );
    $count = $7; #Possibly redundant; Use it if you're aggregating.
    if (exits $selection{$dt->day_of_week}
     && exists $selection{$dt->day_of_week}{$dt->hour}) {
      print $line;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see where you're going. I'll try this and check back in later. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution I'm using is from dlamblin ( Thanks again for your help!! ).

Here's the adjusted YAML config:

```
- branch: Headquarters
  abbrev: HQ
  months: [04, 06]
  DOW:
      1:    {12: 1, 13: 1, 14: 1, 15: 1,
            16: 1, 17: 1, 18: 1}
      2:    {12: 2, 13: 2, 14: 2, 15: 2,
            16: 2, 17: 2, 18: 2}
      3:    {09: 3, 10: 3, 11: 3, 12: 3,
            13: 3, 14: 3, 15: 3, 16: 3, 17: 3, 18: 3}
      4:    {12: 4, 13: 4, 14: 4, 15: 4, 16: 4,
            17: 4, 18: 4, 19: 4, 20: 4}
```

Here's the Perl:

```
foreach my $dir (@dirs) {
    my $file = qq($dir/$abbrev.csv);
    open(F, $file);
    my @data=<F>;
    foreach my $line (@data) {
        chomp($line);
        unless ($line =~ m/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+), (\d+):(\d+):(\d+) , (\d+)/){next;}
        my $dt = DateTime->new( year    => $1,
                                month  => $2,
                                day    => $3,
                                hour   => $4,
                                minute => $5,
                                second => $6,
                                );
         my $count = $7;
         if (exists $DOW{$dt->day_of_week} && exists $DOW{$dt->day_of_week}{$dt->hour}) {
             print $line . "\n";
         }
     }
     close(F);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are modules that will give you the dow from the date and time you have, but if they are too heavy you can `use Time::Local`.  Parse the date--you'll need to do this anyway I think--on each line and feed it through `timelocal`, then through `localtime` which will give you the dow.  You'll have to massage $mon and $year appropriately.

```
$dow = ( localtime( timelocal( 0, 0, 0, $mday, $mon, $year ) ) )[6];
```

Once you've got the dow for the entry you'll know what to do with it.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out. That would simplify things.